# explanation of simple linear regression model proof

Tags: regression

[image]

Hello
As you can see, they ask for proof for equation (2).
The answer is:

$$E(y) = E(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon).$$

Then
$$E(y)= E(\beta_0) + E(\beta_1) + \underbrace{E(\varepsilon)}_{=0}$$

How did he get 0 and where did $X$ go?

Then

$$Var(y) = Var(\beta_0 + \beta_1 X + \varepsilon)$$
$$Var(y) = Var(\beta_0)+ Var(\beta_1 X) + Var(\varepsilon) \beta_0 + \beta_1 X$$

How did he get $\beta_0 + \beta_1 X$?

Comment: (1) Epsilon is assumed to have mean 0, as stated in the prompt.  E[eps]=0 is what "mean zero" means.  (2) I'm not sure what's up with that "B0 + B1X" answer because Var(beta0 + beta1*X + eps) = Var(eps).

Comment: I'm assuming that "he" is the teacher or teaching assistant who gave you the solution. Is it possible that some information might have been lost in the transcription of the solution? Would it be possible for you to show us how *you* would have done it?

Comment: "$X$" vanished into the typographical ether, only to re-emerge (correctly) at the end: that's obviously a typesetting error, not a mathematical one.  He "got $0$" from the fourth stipulation after "where."  At the end, your expansion of the variance is incorrect, so perhaps that is the concept you ought to review first.